# Silverlight 4 application is not running in OOB mode in MAC when cookies from third parties are blocked

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, safari

My Silverlight 4 application runs just fine in Windows OS both in In-Browser and Out Of Browser (OOB) mode. I have issue when running my app on a MAC machine (version 10.6).

When MAC Safari 'Block Cookies' privacy preference is set to 'Never', my Silverlight application is running just fine in both In-Browser and OOB.

When 'Block Cookies' privacy preference is set to 'From third parties and advertisers', my application is NOT working in OOB, but works fine in In-Browser.

I want to get my application running in OOB mode when MAC Safari's 'Block Cookies' privacy preference is set to 'From third parties and advertisers'.

I found that the cookies from my application is blocked in OOB mode. I wonder why it happens only in MAC OOB.

Thanks for your help in advance.